# Stacking issue in internet explorer with z-index

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I am not really good with CSS, so I am having trouble making IE show my menu bar properly. As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhnLj/9/) I have a simple bar where the user can click on his username to display some options.

This code works fine in chrome and firefox, but it does this on internet explorer:
[image]

As you can see, the menu opens inside the navbar, so you will only see the first option.

Can you open this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhnLj/9/) and tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!!

---

SOLUTION:

Wow this is really weird, but it was this line on the CSS!! That is why it works in the fidle, because i put a simle background for the example. For future reference, NEVER do this if you have stacking going on:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5b5b5b', endColorstr='#282828',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I view the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhnLj/9/) in Internet Explorer 9 and turn to IE 8 in development mode and I can see all the options. Not sure how to re-produce the bug you have.

Comment: My internet explorer version is 8.0.7601.17514

Comment: I've tried both IEtester and IE8 in development mode of IE9 and still couldn't re-produce the bug.

You can try put "overflow:visible" for #nav_container to see if it fix the problem.

Comment: Apparently it was the z-index set on #nav_container... Deleting it made it work!

Comment: kinda weird that only your IE8 can see that bug

Answer (score 0):

Modify the CSS of `#user_menu` to the following:

```
top: 30px;
```

Comment: Nope, that would only move down the user menu, but it wouldn't make it display OVER the navbar! Thanks anyway

Comment: fiddler is not able to reproduce bug mentioned in IE8 and IE9

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to the parent item and `position: absolute` to the dropdown. You'll probably also need to alter the `top` attribute of #user_menu so it doesn't overlap the username (about 20px or so should do).

[More on the IE bug here](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/).